# PouchDB get remote data then remove it from device

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am using pouchDB in place of local storage for my Ionic application. I want to fetch data from an existing cloud pouchdb database and use it temporarily without keeping it on my device.

How would one do that?

I'm assuming once I do the following, my data is now stored on my device right?

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://website.com:00/database');
db.get('mydoc').then(function(doc) {
    //do things
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an in-memory PouchDB database (use the in-memory adapter)
2. Replicate from the source to the in-memory db

> I'm assuming once I do the following, my data is now stored on my device right?

No. If you connect to a remote database, the data isn't stored locally automatically. PouchDB just acts as a client for the remote database.

Comment: If it doesn't store locally do I need the in-memory adaptor?

Comment: It can be useful in case you want to provide a limited offline experience

Comment: Didn't quite answer my question. Whats the difference if it already doesn't store locally